# take a particular key from list and store to another list using stream

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a Class with these fields

```
class ListA {
    Long id
    double lat
    doubel lon
    Timestamp timestamp
}
```

I need to make a new list which will only have `lat, lon`

```
class LatLng {
    double lat
    double lon
}
```

how can I do this using streams in Java?

I am able to do this using native for loop. But I want to learn to do it using stream.

```
List<ListA> listAs = this.dao.findAll();

List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList();
for (ListA listA : listAs) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(listA.getLat(), listA.getLon());
    latLngs.add(latlng)
}
```

I just want to pluck lat and lon from ListA and store it to LatLng.

Comment: how would you do it with a loop? add a code example, please

Comment: Before you can do it with a loop or a stream you have to specify the filtering criteria.  What rule specifies the items you want to keep?  Also, I don't think the list contains just the string values... You really need to show the actual definition of the list and the code you've written so far.

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry, I assumed people would understand.

Comment: I already answer with this solution `List<LatLng> newList = listAs.stream()
            .map(p -> new LatLng(p.lat, p.lon))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());` but i get down-votes because you don't provide much information, hope this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
List<ListA> listAs = this.dao.findAll();

List<LatLng> latLngs = listAs.stream()
                .map(listA -> new LatLng(listA.getLat(), listA.getLon()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or even this to save a variable :

```
List<LatLng> latLngs = this.dao.findAll().stream()
                .map(listA -> new LatLng(listA.getLat(), listA.getLon()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in this case by filtering on size == 3 because that is an identifier for these two. You can of course also filter on any other characteristic.

```
final List<String> newItems = items.stream()
                                   .filter(s -> s.length() == 3)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

UPDATE: better solution...

```
final List<String> newItems = items.stream()
            .filter(s -> "lat".equals(s) || "lon".equals(s))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ...until the list contains `id, lat, lon, alt, timestamp`.   Filtering on length is just wrong.

Comment: I had created this answer before it was changed to the current version. Classes were not in the question then...